# Get current working directory of java application in OSX using Java 6

Tags: java, macos, file, netbeans, java-6

I have written an application in Java 6 and it resides in `/applications/test/myApp` directory. 
In my application when I do a `System.getproperty(user.dir)` it returns only `"/"` instead of `"/applications/test/myApp"`
Need help in getting the full path.

My problem statement: User will launch `/applications/test/myApp/parent.app`. Once this application is launched my code should launch `/applications/test/child.app`. I'm able to do this in Windows 7 using System.getproperty with ease. Mac OSX not behaving as expected.

Comment: Try and use `new File(".").getCanonicalFile()`

Comment: @fge Which will return the `user.dir`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer well, who knows

Comment: user.dir not helping. I tried recording output of system command `pwd` as well. It's returning `"/"`

Comment: Yes, this is pain, no, there is very little you can do about. I've used [Java Application Bundler](http://java.net/projects/appbundler) before and the puts in you in the `user.home` directory. Generally speaking though, if you know where the application is typically stored, you could try "seeking" for it manually

Comment: This then means that the program _really_ runs at the root... I don't see much around it except for resorting to native stuff (maybe MacOS X has the equivalent of Linux' s /proc/<pid>/cmdline?)

Comment: @Fge If it's anything like my experience...beside's that's exactly what `user.dir` tells you, the working directory (.) you application is running from :P

Comment: How can it run from root if I'm launching from `/applications/test/myApp`

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, how are you running the app?  Is the app bundled as "MacOS Application Bundle" (.app)?

Comment: How, exactly, is the application launched? I mean the shell command that's ultimately executed ("java ...")

Comment: @MadProgrammer not that I doubt it, but you know, well, bugs ;)

Comment: It's installed by user. Very similar to netbeans installation you can say. Then user launches the app from finder.